# create position independent object file from LLVM bit code

Tags: linux, llvm, dynamic-linking

I have a llvm module that i've dumped as bitcode file with `llvm::WriteBitcodeToFile`. I want to turn this bitcode file into an native dynamically loadable library that contains the functions in the module.

How do i do this? i tried using `llc` for this, but this produces code that apparently is not relocatable, since after doing the following steps:

```
llc -enable-pie -cppgen=functions -filetype=asm executableModule -o em.s
```

then, assemblying with gnu `as` into an object file:

```
as -o mylib.o em.s
```

finally, trying to produce a shared library with:

```
gcc -shared -o libmyfile.so -fPIC mylib.o
```

fails with the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: error: mylib.o: requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'X.foo' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to setup relocation model. Something like -llc -relocation-model=pic. Do not use PIE, because it's for executables, not for libraries. Also, -cppgen does not make any sense here, it's for cpp backend only.

Comment: thanks!!!!, is there a tool to build the library directly from the IR bit code, without relying on the assembler?

Comment: i've seen that llc support native code output, but it is experimental. Is there a production-quality approach for that?

Comment: Hi. Would you tell where option "-relocation-model" is described? I can find it for "lli", but "lli" is not "llc".

Comment: @beroal It is described in the output of `llc --help`. Sadly the manpages do only contain a mere fraction of llc's options. Took me 1 1/2 days to figure out llc had this flag.